# Executing a multi-line command on windows with _popen

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to execute a command that's multiple lines long with `_popen` and capture its output. However when ran, only the first line appear to execute:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const char* command = R"(
        echo Line 1
        echo Line 2
        echo Line 3
    )";

    FILE* pipe = _popen(command, "r");
    if (!pipe) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open pipe." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    char buffer[128];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), pipe) != nullptr) {
        std::cout << buffer;
    }

    _pclose(pipe);
}
```

only outputs:

```
Line 1
```

Is there a proper way to pass mutli-line commands to `_popen`?

This is just an example, the command I'm trying to run cannot be compressed into a single line.

Comment: Short: No it's not possible. The string is passed to the command-interpreter as a *single* command. If you want to execute multiple commands then `_popen` is probably not the best solution to begin with, but if you need to use it then you could create a script that you invoke.

Comment: It's C++, not C

Comment: Is that a Windows thing, @Someprogrammerdude?  The string is passed to the command interpreter as a single input, yes, but that's not the same as a single *command*, at least not when the command interpreter is a POSIX shell.  On Linux or Mac, one can successfully do something similar to what the OP is attempting.

Comment: The string you pass to `popen` is going to be passed through to the command interpreter, still as a single string. So the real question is mostly how you represent multiple commands in a single string for the command interpreter you're using. For one possibility, with most command interpreters you can use `&&` to string commands together: `echo Line 1 && echo Line 2 && echo Line 3`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The POSIX documentation is not clear, and recursive. The [`popen`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) call uses `sh -c "command"`. And the [`sh`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) documentation says that the command string is executed like `system`. And the [`system`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) says the command is executed as `sh -c "command"`... Newline-separated commands isn't mentioned at all.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I acknowledge the recursion, but we don't need to enter that to get to the specification that the string "shall be interpreted by the shell as ***one or more*** commands" (emphasis added), which is my primary point.  And in practice, it can be observed that at least the most prominent shells that are used as `/bin/sh` (Bash, Zsh) do recognize multiple semicolon- or newline-separated commands in that string.